# How to cancel jQuery animate using scroll

Tags: scroll, jquery-animate

I have this jQuery animation, but I need the scroll animation to stop when I scroll.

```js
document.onkeyup = () => {
    $("html").animate({
        scrollTop: "+=500",
    }, {
    duration: 500,
        queue: false,
    });
}
document.onscroll = () => {
    console.log("scrolling");
}
```

```css
p {
     height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> sample </p>
<p> sample </p>
<p> sample </p>
<p> sample </p>
<p> sample </p>
<p> sample </p>
```

In the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) of animate, I saw that you could turn the animation off using `jQuery.fx.off = true`, but I don't know how to effectively use it in this case. Is there I way to do this?

Comment: [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: @JJJ thanks, but how can I distinguish the scroll animation from the ui action, in order to stop it when I scroll?

Comment: The animation doesn't trigger a scroll event.

Comment: @JJJ I updated the snippet,  somehow  the animation is triggering a scroll event

Comment: Sorry, my mistake – it does trigger the event.